# Can you create a foreign key to spring security userdetails user?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-security

I am trying to create a schema where a User can Vote on two Things. It is important that the User does not Vote on the same two Things. To accomplish this I am trying to create a schema where a Vote has a reference to two Things and the User.

The issue is I cannot create a hibernate JoinColumn relationship to [Spring Security's User](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html) as User is not an entity.

Is it possible for me to create this relationship?
Is there a better approach for having Vote have a reference to the User?

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"winnerThingID", "loserThingID", "userID"})})
public class Vote {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer voteID;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="winnerThingID",foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="FK_vote_2"))
private Thing winnerThing;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="loserThingID",foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="FK_vote_3"))
private Thing loserThing;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="userID",foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="FK_vote_4"))
private User user;
```

Comment: In an RDBMS you can create an FK to any table you want. You just cannot do it via JPA annotations

Answer (score 0):

Spring's `User` class is a simple class, not an entity as you would need to model the foreign key relationship. Generally, you should define a specific `User` entity tailored for your application needs, and use that one in the modelling of relations between entities.

Spring security `User` represents an authenticated user in the context of your application. You should do the necessary implementations/extensions of Spring services in such a way that you will need your's `User` entity data when Spring needs to perform authentication with credentials.